# Hello I would like to change base field attribute in odoo

Tags: attributes, odoo

I try to change a base field attributes and follow that video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6bIgk4mtfQ4 it'is running well with required or readonly attributes to 1 but don't with the translate attribute to True or 1. I precise that it's an online version and I can't create my own module to inherit that attributes.
this code is running well

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
<xpath expr="//field[@name='url']" position= "attributes">
    <attribute name="required">1</attribute>/>
</xpath>
</data>
```

Not that one

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
<xpath expr="//field[@name='url']" position= "attributes">
    <attribute name="translate">1</attribute>/>
</xpath>
</data>
```

Rgds

Answer (score 0):

Making a field translatable have do be done on field definition IIRC. So you have to create a custom module for that and just "redefine" the field.

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
   _inherit = "my.model"

   my_field = fields.Char(translate=True)
```

That's the thing for base fields, fields created by modules and apps. For custom fields, fields created in the GUI (either directly or by Odoo Studio) you can just set "Translatable" as you want.

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer, but unfortunaly, it's an online version without studio and I have no other way than create an new inherited view in the backend.

Comment: If it's the "simple" online version you are probably not allowed to make such changes, because it has auto updates and those would fail with such a drastic change.

Comment: Let me explain further: since Odoo 16 translatable fields use another column type in database, that's why i call it a drastic change. In older versions it was separated, translations were saved in an extra table in database. And if there were no translations for a field yet, odoo just took the value saved for that row. So in older versions i wouldn't call it a drastic change.